# Best way to half fill binary search tree for test

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'd like to set up a test to see how fast a tree can be altered by multiple threads in order to do so I need to set up an initial tree with keys in the range 0-((2^n)-1) that has say all the even nodes inserted to form a balanced tree. 
Say for n=4;
we would need to insert 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14 but in this order; [8],[4,12],[0,2,6,10,14]. or [6],[2,10],[0,4,8,14,12] would produce an equally balanced tree.
Currently, I just add 2^(n-1) i.e. [8] then every second multiple of 2^(n-2) i.e. [4,12] then every second multiple of 2^(n-3) i.e. [2,6,10,14] and so on, then I add 0 at the end. 
 Here is the code in C++, but I'm not too worried about language specifics more the algorithm itself.

```
        BST tree = BST();           
        INT64 diff = HMK;//HMK = Half Max Key
        INT64 arrayN[HMK];
        INT64 cur = diff;
        INT64 i = 0;
        Node aNode[HMK];
        while (diff >= 2) {
            cur = diff;
            while (cur < MAX_KEY) {
                aNode[i] = Node();
                aNode[i].key=cur;
                tree.add(&aNode[i]);
                i++;
                cur += 2*diff;
            }
            diff = diff / 2;
        }
        aNode[i] = Node();
        aNode[i].key = 0;
        tree.add(&aNode[i]);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: "how fast a tree can be altered by multiple threads" - this is non-trivial, not addressed in your question, and very dependent on language features.

Comment: I am going implement the tests myself and just gave this information as context as to why I want a half filled binary search tree. Well aware of how it is very language dependant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about changing the tree later on, it may be easiest to first create a skeleton tree graph, and then put in values that are appropriate for the position.

That is to say, since you want values between 0 and `INT_MAX`, the root would be `INT_MAX/2`. *If* there's a left child, it's `INT_MAX/4`; *if* there's a right child it's `3*INT_MAX/4`. The bit pattern should be obvious: `100....`, `010`...`,`110...`. Obviously this is limited to N levels, because at depth D the (N-D)'th bit must be set.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense, hadn't thought of it in terms of the left and right children. Managed to make a recursive function based on this idea.